# How to overload the operator[] with multiple subscripts

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++23, subscript-operator

C++23 added support for overloading operator[] with multiple subscripts. It's now available on GCC 12. How should one make use of it?

An example struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    int& operator[]( const std::size_t row,
                     const std::size_t col,
                     const std::size_t dep )
    {
        return matrix[row][col][dep];
    }

    int matrix[5][5][5];
};
```

I want to use it like this:

```
Foo fooObject;
fooObject.matrix[ 0, 0, 0 ] = 5;
```

But it does not compile;

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [5][5]'
```

It also shows a warning:

```
warning: top-level comma expression in array subscript changed meaning in C++23 [-Wcomma-subscript]
```

Comment: `fooObject.matrix[ 0, 0, 0 ]` -> `fooObject[ 0, 0, 0 ]`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh my bad. So is my solution correct? And how should I implement it for const objects?

Comment: _"And how should I implement it for const objects"_: you should ask a new question for this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fooObject[ 0, 0, 0 ] = 5;
```

not

```
fooObject.matrix[ 0, 0, 0 ] = 5;
```

you should also add compile option `--std=c++23`.