# Is there a way I could overload operator[] with multiple parameters?

Tags: c++, c++14, operator-overloading

I have the following code, and it is giving following error: `binary 'operator [' has too many parameters`

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {
public:
    T operator[](int x, int y) {
        //...
    }
};
```

Is there a way I could overload the `[]` operator with multiple parameters?

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of relates SO posts for this. [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936399/c-array-operator-with-multiple-arguments), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032743/can-cs-operator-take-more-than-one-argument) and [Dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182371/how-to-overload-the-operator-with-multiple-subscripts).

Comment: `T operator[](std::pair<int, int> xy) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Instead, you can overload `operator()` and have people use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need C++23 to overload `operator[]` with multiple parameters. Before that you can use a named function:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {
public:
    T get(int x, int y) {
        //...
    }
};
```

or `operator()` which can be overloaded with arbitrary number of parameters.

PS: If you are like me then you will wonder how that change (only one parameter allowed -> any number allowed) was possible in the presence of the comma operator. The way this is fine is that since C++23 you need parenthesis to call the comma operator (ie `a[b,c]` never calls `operator,(b,c)`, while `a[(b,c)]` does, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).